# Comparing Values -MAT-

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I'd like to find out how a mathematician would think to solve this problem. This question has to be done without the use of calculators and using only basic assumptions.

> **B.** Which is the smallest of these values?
>   $$(a)~\log_{10}\pi,~~~~(b)~\sqrt{\log_{10}(\pi^2)},~~~~(c)~\left(\frac1{\log_{10}\pi}\right)^3,~~~~(d)~\frac1{\log_{10}\sqrt{\pi}}.$$

Comment: Are you going to do the MAT test for Oxford?

Comment: Yeah, I am, but all the questions look so unfamiliar. :v

Comment: As someone doing studying for the test right now, these type of questions are normally approached from an approximation standpoint, so mainly intuition. I would say dedicate 1 hour to multiple choice, and then do 2 other questions of the other 4 because you get more grades for finishing the question than you do for attempting. So each multiple choice should take you 6 minutes, which gives you enough time to do a small bit of calculation for these questions. Like $10^x = 3$, $10^{0.3} < x < 10^{0.6}$ and do this for each one. The questions aren't designed to trick you.

Comment: For $(b)$ do $\sqrt{2\log(\pi)} = \sqrt{2}{\sqrt{log(\pi)}}$ so that's already greater than $(a)$ since the square root between $0 < 1 <$ is always greater than the number itself. For $(c)$ $1/(3\log(\pi))$ and $2/\log(\pi)$ it's mainly guess work, but as you can see $(d) > (c)$. This is just what you should be looking for.

Comment: @JohnMiller Thanks bud. Your explanation was perfect. I'd like to ask how you are preparing for the MAT and what score you are currently getting? I did the specimen paper a few days ago which I've heard is much easier than the recent papers and scored 50 marks. So, I am worried that I will get even lower in the real thing. Do you use any resources to assist your revision?

Comment: I'm getting between 60-70 on most updated papers, the main thing that's helping me is the NRICH guides online as they help you with how to think. I'd also try and make sure you've brushed up on all the components of the syllabus of the MAT as that's all they're allowed to ask you for. It is a very challenging test and I feel they do not do enough for students whose schools do not properly support them (I have been told not to apply on numerous occasions by my teachers).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any serious math calculations for this just rough approximations.

$\pi<10$ so answer $(a) < 1$ while $(c)$ and $(d) > 1$

For $(b), \pi^2$ is close to $10$ so $(b)$ is close to 1, whereas $(a)$ is a much smaller than $1$.

Answer (score 0):

It is very useful to know that $\pi \approx 3.14, \sqrt {10}\approx 3.16,$ so $\pi^2 \approx 10, \log_{10}\pi \approx 0.5$.

a is about $0.5$
b is about $1$
c is about $8$
d is  $\frac 1{\frac 12 \log_{10}\pi} \approx 4$